# Pass the try statement but the database won't update in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview which controlled by 3 buttons (Add, Edit, and Remove). One of the buttons is Edit button. The 2 other buttons work well. It also has 2 textboxes, Task and Priority which if a row in the datagridview is selected then the columns' value will be passed to each textbox

I don't know if there is any problem with the code below.

The table in the database only has 2 columns, Task, and Priority.

When I clicked the edit button, the try statement gives me success message but the database won't update as well as the datagridview.

Is there any solution?

```
void EditItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (taskTb.Text != "" && priorityTb.Text != ""){
            koneksi.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update todo set Task=@task, Priority=@priority where Task=@task", koneksi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"task", taskTb.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"priority", priorityTb.Text);
            try{
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Edited", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            koneksi.Close();
            readData();
        }
        else{
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to edit");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your query is correct? If you run it through a client like SQL Workbench will it work properly? And by work properly I mean will it have the intended result, because it doesn't look like it would cause a syntax error.

Comment: Maybe it is updating correctly but you are not seeing any changes because of `SET Task=@task WHERE Task=@task`? You are updating the value in `Task` to the same value.

Comment: @stybl Yes. I have tried it on SQL Workbench.

Comment: @waka So, how is the solution? it's weird, I have ever used it that query on other project. But it doen't work when I am doing this project.

Comment: Okay, are you sure that a task with the right name exists in the database? Maybe the `WHERE` statement isn't finding anything.

Comment: @stybl yes, it is `Task` and `Priority`.

Comment: Try stepping through the program with the debugger and check all the simple stuff. Things like the actual value of `taskTb.Text` and `priorityTb.Text`. Because the code itself looks fine. The problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx).

Comment: @billyhalim25 I don't have a slution, I was just asking myself if it's really useful to update the `Task` column to be the same value as before. If it updates, you won't see it, as it's the same than before. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your query.
You can't pass task and priority then update it by passed task.

Solution:

```
"update todo set Task=@task, Priority=@priority where id=@id"
```

Comment: Thanks @wedo. However there is no textbox for `id`. What should I assign to the `id` although I have `id` column in database?

Comment: Retrieve it from database table or any other unique field [read id](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: Nice little tutorial on [Relation  Database Design](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html)